# How to render an image from a remote url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to render a remote url (which is an image) as an image in an active admin show page, but those images are from a collection:

```
    panel 'Media Items' do
      render collection: record.chore.media_items.where(discrete_type: :image)
    end
```

But I haven't been able to find anything that does both of these things.

The image url is stored as: chore.media_items.where(discrete_type: :image).first.url for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use literal arbre syntax this way and it might work:

```
panel 'Media Items' do
  record.chore.media_items.where(discrete_type: :image).each do |image|
    img(:src => image.url, :style => 'height: 200px')
  end
end
```

Instead of inline-styling, you could also pass a `:class => 'yourCustomCssClass'` to `arbre's` `img` dsl statement. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
panel 'Media Items' do
  record.chore.media_items.where(discrete_type: :image).each do |image|
    image_tag image.url
  end
end
```

Comment: Not quite for some reason it displays the full object, and doesn't render the image.